# heroku asking for debugger on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Heroku will not deploy. I'm getting the following error:

```
2013-07-20T05:46:05.382706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 15871`
2013-07-20T05:46:10.657881+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-07-20T05:46:10.658274+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-07-20T05:46:13.705246+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-07-20T05:46:13.705246+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:15871
2013-07-20T05:46:13.705246+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-07-20T05:46:13.705246+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-07-20T05:46:13.705246+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-07-20T05:46:18.032181+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- debugger (LoadError)
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035248+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035421+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035421+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035421+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035421+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035421+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035421+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.035421+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043408+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.043631+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-07-20T05:46:18.045133+00:00 app[web.1]:  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-07-20T05:46:19.556879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-07-20T05:46:19.566212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have no debugger in my Gemfile (nor in my Gemfile.lock). Incidentally, Heroku is asking for ruby 1.9.1 when my Gemfile specifies 1.9.3.

I've run 'rvm gemset create [myapp]' and 'rvm gemset use [myapp]' to force my local rails to use a local gemset (as opposed to system gems) and the app runs locally no problem.

Basically, it says it's looking for a debugger. I have no understanding why this is. Any (useful) insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you attach result of `heroku config`? (just cut out any secrects you have in there)

Comment: `=== myApp Config Vars`

`DATABASE_URL:               postgres://...`

`HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TEAL_URL: postgres://...`

`PATH: bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
heroku config:unset PATH
```

Comment: I actually added those paths as per heroku's isntructions. It wasn't working before. It didn't work after and after removing them it still doesn't work. I don't think it's a question of paths. For some reason it's looking for debugger.

I've even run 'heroku run bundle install debugger' to no avail.

Comment: of course it is matter of paths. remove it and do `git push --force` and it should work OR at least change error msg